# How to fully disable network request from vs code(telemetry, updates, etc.)

Tags: request, visual-studio-code, telemetry

Built from the latest sources.

I am trying to prevent vs code to make any network requests(checking for updates, telemetry, etc.).

I tried this

```
config: { 
"telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
 "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
 "update.channel": "none",
 "extensions.autoUpdate": false,
 "git.enabled": false 
}
```

but there are still tcp connections made to the marketplace and microsoft telemetry services.

How do I fully disable network requests without an external firewall?

Comment: Not sure if this issue related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47687

Comment: Also, you can try disabling this: `"workbench.settings.enableNaturalLanguageSearch": false,`

Comment: still sending requests :/

Comment: vscode is MIT but the build is closed (and whatever goes into the binary) will make it to you installtion happily syncing your data. https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/80d8wu/just_realised_that_visual_studio_code_sends/duvaf76?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x